# Boot from live USB on PRO B550M-VC WIFI

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I have a fresh build based on the [MSI PRO B550M-VC WIFI motherboard](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/PRO-B550M-VC-WIFI/support#bios). I've installed the latest BIOS and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.3 on it via live USB.

- I know the USB works because I've used it to install Ubuntu on the computer I'm typing this from, and a couple of others
- I know the target machine works fine because I can use a spare Debian hard drive to boot it and poke around
- I've disabled UEFI boot in BIOS (LEGACY+UEFI in boot options and set the "Windows OS Configuration" option to CSM. There has never been a windows installation on this computer and hopefully never will be)

When I insert the live USB and select "Try or Install Ubuntu", it starts the boot routine and hangs. If I hit `e` and remove `quiet splash`, it goes into

```
booting command list
```

then dumps out a bunch of hardware connection messages (all successful, including the USB key and the SATA drive I'm tying to install to), ending with my USB keyboard and then hangs there. I've let it sit longer than 15 minutes and haven't seen it progress further.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. What graphics chip/card is there (brand name and model)? 2. Did you check with `sha256sum` that the download of the iso file was good? 3. Which tool did you use to create the USB boot drive?

Comment: 1. Zotac RTX 3050 2. No, but given that I was able to flash a USB drive with it, and then perform a working installation with said drive implies that it _was_ good. 3. `dd`

Comment: If I understand correctly, the graphics card has an nvidia chip. It makes me suspect that the graphics driver does not work correctly. Please try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. If successful, you can try to install a proprietary graphics driver.

Comment: An alternative is to try with the [newest available Ubuntu, 'Mantic'](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/446/builds/288055/downloads) to be released within approx. a week as 23.10. It has a newer linux kernel and built-in graphics drivers, and it might also work better with a suitable proprietary graphics driver. - You may need `nomodeset` here too. - I am linking to the 'ISO testing tracker' for the final stage of development, actually outside the scope of Askubuntu, but we are so close, that I think it is worthwhile in this case.

Comment: @sudodus - Yup; that worked :p I added `nomodeset` as part of the boot command by hitting `e` on the "Try or Install Ubuntu" menu option. That got into the boot menu of 22.04.3 I'm very tempted to try 23.10 and report the results. Wanna put that up as an answer?

Comment: Also, yup, 23.04 just works out of the box. I'll check back in in a while; I'll accept your answer if you post it, otherwise I'll add one of my own.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you find a solution :-)

Comment: The link in my previous comment is deprecated. There is working link in the answer, this time to the 'current mantic legacy iso file'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a dialogue via comments, we found the following tips useful.

- If I understand correctly, the graphics card has an nvidia chip. It makes me suspect that the graphics driver does not work correctly. Please try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. If successful, you can try to install a proprietary graphics driver.
- An alternative is to try with the [newest available Ubuntu, 'Mantic'](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-legacy/current/) to be released within approx. a week as 23.10. It has a newer linux kernel and built-in graphics drivers, and it might also work better with a suitable proprietary graphics driver. - You may need `nomodeset` here too. - I am linking to the 'ISO testing tracker' for the final stage of development, actually outside the scope of Askubuntu, but we are so close, that I think it is worthwhile in this case.

---

Finally, Inaimathi. the original poster, found that Ubuntu 23.04 is new enough to manage the graphics card.