# Can't install UEFI ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, uefi

I burned the 22.04.3 version of ubuntu to my disc as gpt in rufus. I boot from flashtan and when I press "try or install ubuntu" it stays on the black screen. secure boot is on on my system.

system:
r5 5600
rtx 3060 12gb
gigabyte a520m k
crucial p3 500gb nvme ssd

Comment: Welcome to Askunbuntu.  Have you hashchecked the downloaded ISO?  Have you tried with secure boot off (really should not make a difference but...)? Maybe try adding "modeset" to the linux line (at the grub menu when on the "try..." type e to edit, instructions at bottom of screen). Add information to your original posting rather than in comments, which may be removed at some point.

Comment: It sounds to me like you reformatted the ISO during write (*Ubuntu ISOs are intended to be cloned to installation media as then they'll install to BIOS, uEFI & Secure-uEFI machines; when reformatted they may not install to all of those*). I'll suggest using a *cloning* method as used in QA & verifying the media on another device (ie. was the ISO verified prior to write? and the media write verified as being correct; if you reformatted the ISO you'll get a false-positive from the machine that wrote it due to it expecting altered ISO write)

Comment: @kamtasyaa, An alternative in this particular case is to try with a newer version of Ubuntu, 23.04 (or 23.10 which is released right now). Those newer versions have newer linux kernels with newer graphics drivers, that might work with your graphics chip. See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488382/).

Comment: @ubfan1, I use `nomodeset` where there is a fairly new nvidia graphics chip. Is `modeset` an alias or is it doing something else?

Comment: @sudodus Oops, typepo, I meant "nomodeset".

Comment: can you help me with Teamviewer to prepare the installation disk? I couldn't do it, no matter what I did